# SQL SELECT: Create a column that counts how many sub_categories begin with specific letter

Tags: mysql, sql

The query that I'm using is below. I need a 4th column in my result called letter_count, which counts how many sub_categories begin with A, how many begin with B, etc all the way to Z - it would be preferable if this could be done dynamically rather than adding a line for each letter.

An example of the table/result that I'm looking for is displayed at the bottom of this question. I can't work out how to amend the query to get this 4th column.

```
SELECT 
     headings.heading AS sub_category, 
    LEFT( headings.heading, 1 ) AS first_letter, 
    headings.url_code as url_code 
FROM TOWN_TABLE a 
    INNER JOIN headings ON a.Heading=headings.heading 
WHERE Category = 'Classified'
GROUP BY sub_category
ORDER BY sub_category ASC
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+--+
|      sub_category       | first_letter |        url_code         | letter_count |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+--+
| Accountants             | A            | accountants             | 6 |
| Adult Education         | A            | adult education         | 6 |
| Aerials                 | A            | aerials                 | 6 |
| Alarms                  | A            | alarms                  | 6 |
| Architectural Services  | A            | architectural services  | 6 |
| Art & Craft             | A            | art and craft           | 6 |
| Bathrooms               | B            | bathrooms               | 8 |
| Beauty Salons & Therapy | B            | beauty salons & therapy | 8 |
| Bed & Breakfast         | B            | bed and breakfast       | 8 |
| Bedrooms                | B            | bedrooms                | 8 |
| Boiler Maintenance      | B            | boiler maintenance      | 8 |
| Bookkeeping Services    | B            | bookkeeping services    | 8 |
| Builders                | B            | builders                | 8 |
| Builders Merchants      | B            | builders merchants      | 8 |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+--+
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? (What's wrong with SELECT DISTINCT if you just want remove duplicates?)

Comment: @jarlh I'll now update that. I didn't know it would do the same thing. Just a lack of knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Keep the GROUP BY if you want to count

Comment: @Mihai I've now added it back :)

Comment: You need a SUM with case but to repeat the numbers you need to JOIN it as a subquery.How many letters?The alphabet?

Comment: What is `TOWN_TABLE` for? All the data you're looking for comes from the `headings` table

Comment: @Rory TOWN_TABLE refers to a table for a specific town - that table contains a single business on each row - each row also contains a heading eg.Accountants (sub category). I need to refer to that TOWN_TABLE table and join it with the Headings table to make sure I'm not including any headings that don't have any businesses in that town. For example, to avoid returning accountants for a town that doesn't have any accountants - does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a derived table that groups by the first letter to get your counts, then join that on to your original table. It's made messier because you have a couple of conditions on which `headings` you want to look at. If this doesn't immediately work I suggest removing the WHERE and just getting it working without that, so you understand the structure, and then add the WHERE back in.

```
SELECT headings.heading AS sub_category, 
       LEFT( headings.heading, 1 ) AS first_letter, 
       headings.url_code as url_code , 
       letter_counts.letter_count
FROM headings ON a.Heading=headings.heading 
INNER JOIN ( 
      -- make a derived table of each letter and how many 
      -- headings start with it. Only count ones that have
      -- a TOWN_TABLE entry with category Classified.
      select left(h_all.heading,1) as the_letter, 
             count(*) as letter_count
      from headings h_all
      WHERE EXISTS ( select * from TOWN_TABLE t 
                     where t.heading = h_all.heading 
                     AND Category = 'Classified') 
      group by left(h_all.heading,1)
    ) as letter_counts on left(heading.heading,1) = letter_counts.the_letter
WHERE EXISTS ( select * from TOWN_TABLE t 
               where t.heading = headings.heading 
               AND Category = 'Classified') 
order by headings.heading
```

Alternatively in SQL Server you can use a CTE to make it slightly nicer to read. Not sure if CTEs work in mysql:

```
with sub_categories ( first_letter, sub_category ) 
as ( 
     select left( h.heading, 1 ) 
          , h.heading
     from headings h
     where exists( select * from TOWN_TABLE t 
                    where t.heading = h_all.heading 
                    and Category = 'Classified') 
) 
select sc.sub_category
     , sc.first_letter
     , sub_category_counts.the_count
from sub_categories sc
inner join ( 
    select first_letter
         , count(*) as the_count
    from sub_categories
    group by first_letter
) as sub_category_counts on sub_category_counts.first_letter = sc.first_letter
order by sc.sub_category
```

Comment: TOWN_TABLE refers to a table for a specific town - that table contains a single business on each row - each row also contains a heading eg.Accountants (sub category). I need to refer to that TOWN_TABLE table and join it with the Headings table to make sure I'm not including any headings that don't have any businesses in that town. For example, to avoid returning accountants for a town that doesn't have any accountants - does that make sense?

Comment: The second query was causing errors which seems to be because the headings table should be called `headings` and not `heading`. So if I changed `from heading h_all` to `from headings h_all`and `left(headings.heading,1)` I do get a result. But the counts aren't correct so I'm trying to look into why this is.

Comment: maybe `TOWN_TABLE` needs to be used in the sub query? any ideas?

Comment: `Category = 'Classified'` is from TOWN_TABLE

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT 
     headings.heading AS sub_category, 
    LEFT( headings.heading, 1 ) AS first_letter, 
    headings.url_code as url_code , CNT as letter_count
FROM TOWN_TABLE a 
    INNER JOIN headings ON a.Heading=headings.heading 
INNER JOIN (SELECT LEFT( headings.heading, 1 ) AS first_letter, COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT( headings.heading, 1 )) as CNT FROM headings) AS lettercounts
ON lettercounts.first_letter = LEFT( headings.heading, 1 )
WHERE Category = 'Classified'
GROUP BY sub_category
ORDER BY sub_category ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a joined field:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM headings AS lett 
          WHERE LEFT(lett.heading, 1)=first_letter)
    AS letter_count
FROM ...
```

This should take `first_letter` from the outer query and count how many headings start with that letter. If it doesn't work as such, because `first_letter` is an alias, you need to state its value explicitly:

```
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM headings AS lett 
          WHERE LEFT(lett.heading, 1)=LEFT(headings.heading, 1))
    AS letter_count
```

You use `headings` twice, once as itself to get the data you need, the second time to fetch the first letter.

**[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89312f/1/0) is a link to a SQL Fiddle for testing purposes**:

```
SUB_CATEGORY    FIRST_LETTER    URL_CODE            LETTER_COUNT
Accountants     A               /url/accountants    2
Art & Craft     A               /url/arts_crafts    2
Bathrooms       B               /url/bathrooms      1
```